# PHP insert using select and variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my insert statement.  I know SQL pretty well but not much about PHP.  My insert statement is below.   I always get Database error or invalid.  My database is setup correctly since it works on other pages.  I think it is something simple such quote marks etc.

```
$sSQL = INSERT INTO "budget_bdg" ("bgd_grp_ID", "bdg_year", "bdg_alloc" )Select "grp_ID", " . $iFYID ." , "0" from "group_grp";
```

Comment: Pretty much everything.

Comment: Look up **prepared statements**, which guard your code against SQL injection. A good place to get started is the [PHP.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). That will also show you how to write MySQL together with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referencing a table name or column name, use the backtick instead ` (or do not use it at all, if your column/table name contains no spaces).

```
$sSQL = "INSERT INTO `budget_bdg`
        (`bgd_grp_ID`, `bdg_year`, `bdg_alloc` )
        values (select `grp_ID`,
                       '$iFYID'
                        0 from `group_grp`";
```

Keep in mind that this code is unsafe depending on the value of `$iFYID`.

Comment: *"If you're referencing a table name or column name, use the backtick instead"* - Not entirely true. Unless their table/column names contain spaces, or hyphens or a reserved word; yes. Otherwise they're not needed. Just need to clarify on this ;-)

Comment: Thank you Fred. He can indeed use or not use them.

Comment: You're welcome Phiter, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

```
$sSQL = "INSERT INTO budget_bdg (bdg_grp_ID, bdg_year, bdg_alloc) Select grp_ID,   $iFYID , '0' from group_grp";
```